# Running a GHC created windows executable as a service

Tags: windows, haskell, windows-services, ghc

I have compiled a program on `Windows Server 2008` using `GHC 7.6.3` `32-bit`. I'm attempting to run it via a service within windows on boot-up (and ideally keep it up). To do so I have created a service with the following command successfully

`sc create stworker binPath= "C:\Users\vagrant\Desktop\worker.exe"`

The problem I'm having is that when I attempt to start the service I receive the following error (see image below).

The executable runs fine when I double click it. So not sure why Windows wouldn't allow the service to be run.

I don't think this is an issue w/ `GHC`. I'm under the assumption that `GHC` compiles to native code and not `MSIL`.

So any ideas why I can't run my executable as a service?

[image]

Comment: The first line support question, you know that a windows service isn't the same as an application?

Comment: You need calls to StartServiceCtrlDispatcher, RegisterServiceCtrlHandler, SetServiceStatus (at least) in the ServiceMain and a SERVICE_TABLE_ENTRY

Comment: I havn't tried it (because it didn't exist when I needed it) but http://hackage.haskell.org/package/Win32-services

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the comments, you need to actually implement the Win32 service API for your program to behave as a Windows service, and you can do this using the [`Win32-services`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/Win32-services) package.

There's also a wrapper package [`Win32-services-wrapper`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/Win32-services-wrapper) that I wrote that aims to provide some of the boilerplate and handle logging, so that defining a service looks like this:

```
main =
    defineService $
        Service {
            serviceName = "Service",
            -- Start the service given a debug handle to write to.
            -- Make sure not to use stdout or stderr as they don't exist.
            -- Any state needed by serviceStop can be returned here -
            -- the Service type takes the type of the state as a type parameter
            serviceStart = \debugHandle -> ...,
            -- Stop the service given the service state returned by serviceStart
            serviceStop = \serviceState -> ...
        }
```

There's a real example of using it in [`darcsden`](http://hub.darcs.net/simon/darcsden/browse/web-server/darcsden.hs#40).